# How can I change my font and coloring in Oh My Zsh to match a theme I want

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line, zsh, themes

I'm using Oh My Zsh and I was using the "Agnoster" theme for a while, but now I want to switch to "Amuse". So I went into my ~/.zshrc file and changed the theme config line to `ZSH_THEME=amuse`

This only gets me part of the way there. My font and color scheme doesn't seem to match still. The theme is supposed to look like this:
[image]
But mine looks like this:
[image]

I saw the theme on [this page](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes#amuse) but I can't seem to find info on font or coloring, nor can I figure out how to change it in Oh My Zsh manually. I did see the note about Powerline Fonts and I believe I already have those installed because the Agnoster theme I was using previously needed them too.

How can I get my terminal to match the Amuse theme exactly?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The shell defines the basic colours, then you specify how the Terminal displays those colours used in Terminal Preferences, under Profiles then the profile you're using.

[image]